Under what circumstances can an insurance company claim back the cost of setting up a policy?
There is a news story about a 15-year-old Citroën that was towed by the council and the owner was not informed.   The owner assumed it was stolen, claimed against the insurance and was paid out.  Unsurprisingly when the error was identified one year later the insurance company requested the £2,190 paid for the ‘theft’ back.  What is more of a surprise is that they also requested £90 more as "the cost of setting up her policy".  At no point is there an suggestion of any dishonesty from the car owner.  While it is not explicit it is implied this paragraph explains that charge:

“An engineer’s report has concluded that it’s only worth scrap, which, if they’d known, would have invalidated my policy,” she said. “It had only recently passed its MOT when it vanished, but Hastings has so far failed to send me the report and is threatening to send debt collectors.”

What are the circumstances where an insurance company can reclaim the cost of setting up a policy?  It is worth noting that in the UK second hand car prices are low and repair costs and scrap prices are high, such that the difference between a good functioning 15 year old car and scrap value can be a very small repair.

Given that Hastings is not an insurance company but a broker, they would have already charged a set-up fee in the insurance premium.

@WeatherVane I am afraid that means nothing to me WRT why they would be able to claim it back in such a situation.

I mean that the insured person is charged a set-up fee at the time the policy was taken out. So why would the broker now ask for a set-up fee, when the insured person has already paid it?

The fact that it all made so little sense is why I thought it must have an interesting legal answer.

Guess: they'd closed her account so charged the fee to re-open the old account or open a new account to handle the issue.

What I see: when the car was declared a total loss, the policy terminated. The car wasn't a total loss, so the policy was retroactively reinstated, and therefore premiums and the broker's fee are owed for the period. Before the article got paywalled, I think it said the owner made a successful forced entry damage claim, which presumably happened in storage, so that would have been covered under the reinstated policy.
